# Which site can I use to ask about how to control a player's actions in Minecraft?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

[Is it possible to control the player's actions in Minecraft using fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66840618/is-it-possible-to-control-the-players-actions-in-minecraft-using-fabric)

I was told that asking for tutorials or API calls is off-topic on SO, and that I should ask for a site recommendation. Should I go to software recommendations, since I'm not sure if Fabric is the right tool, or where else could I ask my question?

Comment: i don't get it. the close reason suggests that no one else does either.

Comment: noone else does what?

Comment: that no one else gets it. you see, too focused basically means the same thing as needs details. but more specifically it means that there are too many questions in one and so it is too big of a question. but i dunno why they didnt close as off-topic

Comment: I'm confused too, because I pretty much just asked that one question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TL;DR– [Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) may be your best bet, but put in your own research and due diligence.

---

Regarding the question that your post boils down to: "Is it possible to control the player in Minecraft using Fabric?"

From the outside looking in, it *sounds* like "Does Fabric do this thing" would be something that could be answered by Fabric's API documentation ([Fabric's wiki section](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/doku.php#developing_with_fabric) looks like a good start), but maybe that's not the case. I'd definitely check there first, if you haven't already, before asking about it on an SE site.

As for site recommendations– at first, I thought some good site candidates for this would be:

- [Software Recommendations SE](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)
- [Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/)
- [Game Development SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

But now that I've taken a closer look, the first two don't look like good fits for this specific question.

**Software Recommendations SE** [allows asking for](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) library recommendations, which would likely include Minecraft modding libraries/ frameworks, but questions there need to be directly asking for recommendations; your question is more about whether Fabric satisfies your needs.

**Arqade** is the videogame-centered SE site, [but officially doesn't allow questions about game and mod](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) *[development](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*, which your question would fall under. It instead points those questions to Game Dev SE. You may find some relevant information here, but I don't think this is really the right place to ask, at least based on their help center.

**Game Development SE**, on the other hand, [is for videogame development related questions](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), which Minecraft modding falls squarely under ([there's even a minecraft-modding tag](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minecraft-modding)). This is probably your best bet. No guarantees, exchanges, or refunds, but I think that's where I would ask this.